# How is the first child element determined in a belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 invoices that belong to the same shipment. The first invoice created is always the main invoice of the shipment.

```
Invoice 
id   shipment_id
21   55 # This is the main invoice
88   55
93   55
```

If I perform the following query

```
s = Shipment.find(55)
s.invoices[0] # 21
s.invoices[1] # 88
s.invoices[2] # 93
```

So I'm guessing the order of the child elements is determined by their id's. Am I right? Or is there something more to it?

I'm asking because I need to be certain of the order of the child elements to make sure one of my methods will always work.

```
def am_i_the_main_invoice?
  if self.shipment.invoices[0].id == self.id
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an association extension for the sake of readability

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices do
    def main
      @main_invoice ||=  first(:order => "id ASC")
    end

    def main?(id)
      main.try(:id) == id
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can get the main invoice as follows:

```
shipment.invoices.main # returns main invoice
shipment.invoices.main?(23) # checks if the invoice is a main invoice
```

This way, you are cleanly exposing the concept of `main` invoice.

Comment: I had to modify the query because I kept on getting errors, so this is what's inside the `main_invoice` method: `self.invoices(:order => 'id ASC').first`. I like this approach because it doesn't require changes to the database.

Comment: What was the error? Also, I don't think `invoices(:order => 'id ASC')` modifies the sort order. The association method takes `boolean` parameter to reload the association array.  I would use `self.order("id ASC").first`. I have used the code I have given and it has worked for me before.

Answer (score 2):

The order is random unless you explicitly set it. While your database will probably return the elements in the same order right now, it can be a any other order if you change anything (even seemingly unrelated stuff). So again: don't trust the order of elements retrieved from a relational database unless you have explicitly set the order in your query.

In your `Shipment` class where you probably have setup a `has_many` relation, you can add something like `:order => "id ASC"` to always enforce the order by id.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of depending on an ordered query, you could add a flag to the `invoices` table:

```
# in migration
add_column :invoices, :is_primary, :boolean, {null: false, default: false}

# if your rdbms supports partial indexes, you can enforce it
execute 'create unique index uniq_single_primary on invoices (shipment_id) where is_primary = true'

# then query is easy ..
def am_i_the_main_invoice?
  self.is_primary?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The order returned usually depends on the SQL Database you're using. Usually it is based on the primary key, but as [Holger Just](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421705/holger-just) said, don't trust it cause it can change.

You can work around this in 2 ways:

1. Add a scope in your Invoice model, which you can call on before you look through your collection, e.g. `scope :by_shipment, order("id ASC")`
2. Add a default_scope so that it will always be retrieved in that order, e.g. `default_scope order("id ASC")`

Hope this helps

Comment: Only in certain databases (e.g MySQL) you often get data ordered by primar key when not specifying order. However, even MySQL returns unordered data sometimes (e.g after compaction). Other databases like Postgres return out ordered data much more frequent. Generally (according to the various SQL standards) if the order is not specified, it can be random.

Comment: @HolgerJust Personally I always set an order, unless I don't care, because you're right and even MySQL brings them out unordered. SQLite seems to bring them out in order too from what I've seen. But rather be safe than sorry, right ;)